# Mystic with ArgumentOutOfRangeException and System.__Canon

Tags: c#, .net

I've faced with a very strange situation (from my point). On a production machine, my application was crashed due to unhandled exception. Here's the record about exception in 'Application' log:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   Stack:    at
>   LayerCake.UI.ApplicationBootstrapper`2[[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Run()
>   at
>   OCDERP.Client.Shell.Bootstrapper.Main()

I never seen this type (`System.__Canon`, in my code the type definition is `ApplicationBootstrapper<ApplicationVM, Application>`) earlier, so, I've tried to search some info, but there's no much explanations, what it is.

Well, debugging exceptions, when you have stack trace is much easier, isn't it?
But here's the `Run` method, where the stack trace ends (this is a WPF application with Prism-like MVVM framework):

```
    public void Run()
    {
        logger.Debug(Resources.AB_LayerCakeHello);
        logger.Debug(Resources.AB_Starting);
        try
        {
            logger.Debug(Resources.AB_CreatingApplicationCatalog);

            using (var catalog = CreateApplicationCatalog())
            {
                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_CreatingApplicationViewModel);
                var viewModel = CreateApplicationViewModel(catalog);

                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_LoadingMainWindowsSettings);

                var service = viewModel
                    .PartsContainer
                    .GetExportedValue<IApplicationDataService<T>>();

                var settings = service.LoadMainWindowSettings();

                ConfigureWindowSettings(settings);

                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_CreatingApplication);

                var application = new Application();

                InitializeApplicationResources(application);

                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_ShowingMainWindow);
                viewModel
                    .PartsContainer
                    .GetExportedValue<IPresentationService>()
                    .ShowInMainWindow(viewModel, settings);

                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_Running);
                application.Run(); // starting application message loop

                logger.Debug(Resources.AB_SavingWindowSettings);
                service.SaveMainWindowSettings(settings);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e);
            throw;
        }
        logger.Debug(Resources.AB_Stopping);
    }
```

I've no idea, where in this method `ArgumentOutOfRange` could be raised. 
Well, it *could* be raised somewhere in nested methods, but it should be reflected in stack trace.

What am I missing?

P.S. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the bug at the moment.